# How do you pass an array of integers to a stored procedure or function using linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

I was just asked how to go about passing an array of integers into a stored procedure or function using LINQ to SQL.  As I have never done this and don't see anything on Google I figured I would ask here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a table-valued parameter, then AFAIK there is no direct support at the moment. ADO.NET does though. Another option is to build a delimited string, and split it (perhaps in a udf) at the db. Then it is just a `[n]varchar(size)` at the db, and `string` in your code - simply to handle.

Comment: The passing of a delimited string was my initial reaction.  Looks like we will keep that suggestion intact!  Thanks for the confirmation.